# HAProxy setup on a system which does not host any RabbitMQ node

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

I want to set up HAProxy for RabbitMQ cluster. I have following queries on the same:

(1) Suppose I have a scenario where my RabbitMQ server, client, and haproxy are on different machines.

```
RabbitMQ node1   -> Machine1 
RabbitMQ node2   -> Machine2
HAPROXY          -> Machine3
RabbitMQ client  -> Mahcine4
```

`node1` and `node2` have been clustered. Is this a correct configuration? The rationale behind my asking this question is : can HAProxy be setup on a machine which does not host any node or HaProxy has to be setup on a machine which host at least one RabbitMQ server node?

(2) If the above setup is valid, then my RabbitMQ client should know only HAPrxoy machine, and in that case, how shall I connect my client to HAProxy? The client code which works when RabbitMQ client has to connect to a machine hosting RabbitMQ server node will not work here.

Comment: I investigated and found answers of my questions. 1. This set up is valid in the sense it is a possible scenario. 2. Client will connect to HAProxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated and found answers of my questions. 1. This set up is valid in the sense it is a possible scenario. 2. Client will connect to HAProxy server.